How to apply class weights to using Pytorch's CrossEntropyLoss to solve an imbalanced data classification problem for Multi-class Multi-output problem
I'm trying to use a weighted loss function to handle class imbalance in my data. My problem is a multi-class and multi-output problem. For example (my data has five output/target columns (output_1, output_2, output_3) and I have three classes (class_0, class_1, and class_2) in each target column. I am currently using pytorch's cross entropy loss function https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html and I see that it has a weight parameter but my understanding is that this the same weight would be applied uniformly to each output/target, but I want to apply separate weights for each class in each output/target.
For concreteness, I could have data that looks like this



A
B
C
D
E
OUTPUT_1
OUTPUT_2
OUTPUT_3




5.65
3.56
0.94
9.23
6.43
0
2
1


7.43
3.95
1.24
7.22
2.66
0
0
0


9.31
2.42
2.91
2.64
6.28
2
0
2


8.19
5.12
1.32
3.12
8.41
0
2
0


9.35
1.92
3.12
4.13
3.14
0
1
1


8.43
9.72
7.23
8.29
9.18
1
0
2


4.32
2.12
3.84
9.42
8.19
0
1
0


3.92
3.91
2.90
8.19
8.41
2
0
2


7.89
1.92
4.12
8.19
7.28
0
1
2


5.21
2.42
3.10
0.31
1.31
2
0
0



whereby,
     the proportion in output 1 is : 0 = 0.6, 1 = 0.1, 2 = 0.3
     the proportion in output 2 is : 0 = 0.4, 1 = 0.3, 2 = 0.3
     the proportion in output 3 is : 0 = 0.4, 1 = 0.2, 2 = 0.4

I want to apply the class weight based on the distribution of classes in each output column such that it renormalizes (or rebalances? not sure what the terminology to use here is) class 1 to 0.15 and class 0 and class 2 to 0.425 each (so for output_1 the weights would be [0.425/0.6, 0.15/0.1, 0.425/0.3], for output 2 it'll be [0.425/0.4, 0.15/0.3, 0.425/0.3] etc). Rather, what I understand the weight parameter in pytorch's crossentropy loss function is currently doing, is it'll apply a single class weight to each output column. I'm wondering if i'm missing something and there's a way to do this using pytorch's crossentropyloss function?

One possible solution is to call CrossEntropyLoss once for each label/target and add up the losses. This also works if the labels have different numbers of classes.
Here is an example using your data:
inputs = torch.tensor([
    [5.65, 3.56, 0.94, 9.23, 6.43],
    [7.43, 3.95, 1.24, 7.22, 2.66],
    [9.31, 2.42, 2.91, 2.64, 6.28],
    [8.19, 5.12, 1.32, 3.12, 8.41],
    [9.35, 1.92, 3.12, 4.13, 3.14],
    [8.43, 9.72, 7.23, 8.29, 9.18],
    [4.32, 2.12, 3.84, 9.42, 8.19],
    [3.92, 3.91, 2.90, 8.19, 8.41],
    [7.89, 1.92, 4.12, 8.19, 7.28],
    [5.21, 2.42, 3.10, 0.31, 1.31]]) #samples,features
targets = torch.tensor([
    [0, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 2],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 2],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [2, 0, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 0, 0]]) #samples,labels
manual_class_weight = torch.tensor([0.425,0.15,0.425]) #classes
class_counts = torch.stack([label.unique(return_counts=True)[1] \
                           for label in targets.T]) #labels,classes
print(class_counts)
class_weights = manual_class_weight.unsqueeze(0)/class_counts #labels,classes

torch.manual_seed(0)
model = nn.Linear(5,3*3) #features -> labels*classes
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.1)
for epoch in range(100):
    predicted_logits = model(inputs).view(-1,3,3) #samples,labels,classes
    loss = sum(F.cross_entropy(predicted_logits[:,i_label],
                            targets[:,i_label],
                            class_weights[i_label]) \
            for i_label in range(3))
    if epoch%10==0:
        accuracy = (predicted_logits.argmax(dim=2)==targets).float().mean()
        print(f"epoch: {epoch}  loss: {loss:.2f}  accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

This code results in:
tensor([[6, 1, 3],
        [5, 3, 2],
        [4, 2, 4]])
epoch: 0  loss: 13.68  accuracy: 0.20
epoch: 10  loss: 3.59  accuracy: 0.57
epoch: 20  loss: 2.00  accuracy: 0.63
epoch: 30  loss: 1.51  accuracy: 0.73
epoch: 40  loss: 1.22  accuracy: 0.83
epoch: 50  loss: 1.10  accuracy: 0.83
epoch: 60  loss: 1.02  accuracy: 0.87
epoch: 70  loss: 0.97  accuracy: 0.83
epoch: 80  loss: 0.93  accuracy: 0.90
epoch: 90  loss: 0.90  accuracy: 0.87

If all labels have the same number of classes and no (or equal) class weights, then this can be done in parallel with only one call (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/crossentropyloss-for-multiple-output-classification/111660). I wrote some code that achieves parallelism in your case and gives the exact same output as before, but I am not sure whether it is actually faster:
unreduced_loss = F.cross_entropy(
    predicted_logits.permute(0,2,1), #bc. class-dim expected as second!
    targets,reduction="none") #samples,labels
weight = class_weights[torch.arange(3),targets] #samples,labels
loss = (unreduced_loss*weight/weight.sum(0)).sum()

Often it is also suggested to use Binary Cross Entropy for multi-label classification, but I think they aren't mathematically equivalent.
